# Tableview on crash after reload from larger source. numberOfrows doesn't seem to get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What's happening is I have a segmented view control and when I switch segments I will reload my tableview with different data. One segment will reload it with 30+ the other has 11 in this case.
The issue was found when scrolling and switching back and forth, it gets to a point where it's looking for index 30 but only 11 objects are in my array. If I'm not doing this really quick, it's fine.
Scrolling to the top before reloading the table did not help.

Take a look at my logs and notice the pattern, the last log shows that numberOfrows was not called prior to cellforRow

I've tried calling the method that reloads the table on the main thread, waiting until done.

I have also tried scrolling to the top before reload.

The issue seems to be when I'm scrolling fast and switch to the new segment.

The logs are in this order:
1. prior to arranging the data, this is when I click the segment
2. after I arrange the data and swap the arrays
3. in numberOfRows
4. In cellforRows.

The last sequence skips the third step.

```
2014-05-09 15:58:06.193 [2991:8407] Employees had 0  
2014-05-09 15:58:06.216 [2991:8407] Employees has 11 rows after arrangeData
2014-05-09 15:58:06.216 [2991:60b] Returning 11 in numberOfRowsInSection
2014-05-09 15:58:06.217 [2991:60b] Looking for index 0 with employee count of 11 
2014-05-09 15:58:06.227 [2991:60b] Looking for index 1 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:06.236 [2991:60b] Looking for index 2 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:06.244 [2991:60b] Looking for index 3 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:06.971 [2991:60b] Employees had 11
2014-05-09 15:58:07.030 [2991:60b] Employees has 26 rows after arrangeData
2014-05-09 15:58:07.031 [2991:60b] Returning 26 in numberOfRowsInSection
2014-05-09 15:58:07.032 [2991:60b] Looking for index 0 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.034 [2991:60b] Looking for index 1 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.036 [2991:60b] Looking for index 2 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.038 [2991:60b] Looking for index 3 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.525 [2991:60b] Looking for index 4 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.564 [2991:60b] Looking for index 5 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.577 [2991:60b] Looking for index 6 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.641 [2991:60b] Looking for index 7 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.675 [2991:60b] Looking for index 8 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.708 [2991:60b] Looking for index 9 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.758 [2991:60b] Looking for index 10 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.791 [2991:60b] Looking for index 11 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.841 [2991:60b] Looking for index 12 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.908 [2991:60b] Looking for index 13 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:07.958 [2991:60b] Looking for index 14 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:08.042 [2991:60b] Looking for index 15 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:08.125 [2991:60b] Looking for index 16 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:08.225 [2991:60b] Looking for index 17 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:08.341 [2991:60b] Looking for index 18 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:08.450 [2991:60b] Employees had 26
2014-05-09 15:58:08.483 [2991:60b] Employees has 11 rows after arrangeData
2014-05-09 15:58:08.485 [2991:60b] Returning 11 in numberOfRowsInSection
2014-05-09 15:58:08.487 [2991:60b] Looking for index 7 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:08.490 [2991:60b] Looking for index 8 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:08.492 [2991:60b] Looking for index 9 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:08.494 [2991:60b] Looking for index 10 with employee count of 11
2014-05-09 15:58:10.282 [2991:60b] Employees had 11
2014-05-09 15:58:10.329 [2991:60b] Employees has 26 rows after arrangeData
2014-05-09 15:58:10.330 [2991:60b] Returning 26 in numberOfRowsInSection
2014-05-09 15:58:10.331 [2991:60b] Looking for index 7 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.334 [2991:60b] Looking for index 8 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.336 [2991:60b] Looking for index 9 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.338 [2991:60b] Looking for index 10 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.624 [2991:60b] Looking for index 11 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.674 [2991:60b] Looking for index 12 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.690 [2991:60b] Looking for index 13 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.741 [2991:60b] Looking for index 14 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.775 [2991:60b] Looking for index 15 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.808 [2991:60b] Looking for index 16 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.842 [2991:60b] Looking for index 17 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.892 [2991:60b] Looking for index 18 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.941 [2991:60b] Looking for index 19 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:10.991 [2991:60b] Looking for index 20 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:11.042 [2991:60b] Looking for index 21 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:11.108 [2991:60b] Looking for index 22 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:11.175 [2991:60b] Looking for index 23 with employee count of 26
2014-05-09 15:58:11.266 [2991:60b] Employees had 26
2014-05-09 15:58:11.294 [2991:60b] Employees has 11 rows after arrangeData
2014-05-09 15:58:11.296 [2991:60b] Looking for index 24 with employee count of 11
```

Comment: Please post your code - stuff from your table delegate & data source, and also the code that runs when you switch segments.

Comment: Post the code you are invoking when tapping on the segmented control.